# PyGTK - Non flexible box?

Tags: python, button, gtk

In my project in Python GTK, I have a problem with a simple button.
I would like that the box don't be flexible at the user's resize (or block the resize)

The good look:

[image]

But when the user change the window's, height, it should be like this (and the button can disappear):
[image: the button can disapear..]

or like this:

[image: ...or placed very far.]

How can I define a fixed height?

My code:

```
# window
self.fenetre = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL) 
self.fenetre.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
self.fenetre.set_border_width(10)
self.fenetre.set_default_size(self.l, self.h)  # l and h can be memorized in a conf file
self.fenetre.set_icon_from_file("/usr/share/icons/app-ico.png")
self.fenetre.connect("delete_event", self.destroy)
[...]

# notebook, all the other modules are in there
[...]          
self.insert_notebook()
self.notebook.show()

# Nouvelle boite pour le bouton quitter
boite_quit = gtk.HButtonBox()
self.box.add(boite_quit)
boite_quit.set_border_width(10)
boite_quit.set_layout(gtk.BUTTONBOX_END) 

# Bouton quitter
bouton = gtk.Button("Enregister et fermer", gtk.STOCK_QUIT)
bouton.connect("clicked", self.destroy, "bouton B")
boite_quit.pack_start(bouton, False, False, 0)
bouton.show()

boite_quit.show()
self.fenetre.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why you want this particular behavior?

Comment: I feel that it would be better that this button stay in the same place, without disappear.. Or maybe my question should be otherwise presented, like: 'How to set a minimum size for a window'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the window from being resizable, call the `set_resizable` method on the top-level window with a false argument:

```
self.fenetre.set_resizable(False)
```

To specify the minimum size of the window (while still allowing resizes to a larger size), set the size request on the widget:

```
self.fenetre.set_size_request(self.l, self.h)
```